# Inequality with sup inside a Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

Ive got a short question, I wasn't able to solve. Theres the following inequality which I`m trying to understand: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a constant, then
$$ P_{\eta}\bigg(\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{j=1}^m \delta^2_{n,j}>\varepsilon\bigg)\leq m\sup\limits_{j=1,\ldots,m}P_\eta\Big(\delta_{n,j}^2>\varepsilon / 2\Big),$$
where $P_\eta$ is a probability measure and $\delta_{n,j}$ random variables (assume $n$ is fixed so $j$ is the index). Further, I only know, that $\delta$ isn't centered and has finite second moment.

My idea was, that one might start with 
$$ P_{\eta}\bigg(\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{j=1}^m \delta^2_{n,j}>\varepsilon\bigg)\leq P_\eta\bigg(\sup\limits_{j=1,\ldots,m}\delta_{n,j}^2>\epsilon\bigg). $$
But beyond this obvious step, I've had no clue what to do. Maybe some of you can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: So, to simplify the notation, am I wrong or we can actually take out the $\eta$ and the $n$?

Comment: Also, concerning how to proceed, did you try by induction?

Comment: yes indeed!! Sorry for the complicated notation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kolmin said we can omit the $n$ and the $\eta$.  Your idea is correct, then you can use the union bound (Bonferroni's inequality):
$$
%P\left(\frac1m\sum_{j=1}^m \delta_j^2>\epsilon\right)
%\le
 P\left(\sup_{j=1,\dots,m}\delta_j^2>\epsilon\right)
= P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^m\{\delta_j^2>\epsilon\}\right)
\le \sum_{j=1}^m P\left(\delta_j^2>\epsilon\right)
\le m\sup_{j=1,\dots,m}P\left(\delta_j^2>\epsilon\right).
$$
The last inequality is bcecause a sum of $m$ numbers is smaller than $m$ times the maximum of these real numbers.  Of course, $P(\delta_j^2>\epsilon)\le P(\delta_j^2>\epsilon/2)$, which completes the proof.

Comment: thank you! this wasn't too hard as I now realize. I was a bit confused about $\epsilon / 2$, but now it makes perfect sense